# sed で [あ-ゞ] のような日本語の文字範囲を使いたい

Tags: 正規表現, sed, locale

平仮名を判定しようと、`[あ-ゞ]`という正規表現を書いたのですが、`sed`(GNU sed)では使えませんでした。
（この正規表現は間違っています。**平仮名の判定に真似しないで下さい**。sayuriさんの回答を参照のこと）

```
echo "abcあいう123" |sed -re 's/^[あ-ゞ]+//g'
# エラーになる: sed: -e expression #1, char 16: Invalid collation character
```

GNU系の`awk`や`grep`(`-P`オプション付き)では使えるようなのですが、`sed`はどうも駄目なようです。

`[あ-ゞ]`のような正規表現の代替になる手段や、これがそのまま使える`sed`コマンドなどを探しています。
（なぜ使えないのか、という疑問もあります）

---

Ubuntu16.04で、`en_US.UTF-8` と `ja_JP.UTF-8` のロケールでテストしています。
GNU sed は PCRE（libpcre.so.3）にリンクされている物でテストしていますが、`libc`のみの物でも再現しました。
`locale charmap`の実行結果はテストしている`en_US.UTF-8`と`ja_JP.UTF-8`の環境では両方とも、`UTF-8`になります。

Comment: ロケールはutf8でしょうか。一応BSD sedでは問題なく行くのでGNU sedでできないことは無い気が

Comment: @packet0  utf-8 です。`LANG=en_US.UTF-8`以外に`ja_JP.UTF-8`でも試しましたが駄目でした。BSD sed では動くのですね。ありがとうございます。

Comment: GNU sed のソースコードを眺めてみると `echo "abcあいう123" | LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 sed -re 's/^[あ-ゞ]+//g'` とすれば良い様です。

Comment: @metropolis ありがとうございます。たしかに、`LC_CTYPE=UTF-8`で動きました。`LC_CTYPE=XX` のように存在しない適当なロケールを指定しても動くようですので、もう少し調べてみます。

Comment: @mjy さん、追記にも書きましたが`locale charmap`の実行結果が気になるので確認いただけないでしょうか？

Comment: @sayuri 色々情報頂きまして、試した結果を追記しました。どうも、文字範囲として有効かどうかの判定には`LC_COLLATE`が影響しているようです。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

環境変数`LC_COLLATE`に`C.UTF-8`を指定する事で解決しました。

```
echo "abcあいう123" |LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8 sed -re 's/[ぁ-ゞ]/X/g'
#=> abcXXX123
```

`sed`だけでなく、(`-P`オプション無しの GNU) `grep` や`bash`にも有効で、日本語の文字範囲を使えるようになりました。

```
echo "abcあいう123" |LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8 grep -oE '[ぁ-ゞ]+'
#=> あいう
LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8 bash -c '[[ abcあいう123 =~ [ぁ-ゞ]+ ]]; echo $BASH_REMATCH'
#=> あいう
```

- `LC_ALL`が設定されていると、`LC_COLLATE`だけ変えても効果がない
- `LC_CTYPE`と`LC_COLLATE`に互換性の無い値を指定すると、動作は未定義になる
  という[注意点があります](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#FOOT2)。

---

#### `en_US.UTF-8` や `ja_JP.UTF-8` でエラーになった理由

ユニコードでは[平仮名は連続しており](http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~ax2s-kmtn/ref/unicode/u3040.html)、当然に正規表現の文字範囲でも連続しているものとして扱われると思っていたのですが、そうではありませんでした。
[ロケールの`LC_COLLATE`グループ](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xbd/locale.html#tag_005_003_002)では文字の順序が定められており、この順序は正規表現でも使用されます。

そして、Ubuntu16.04のロケール定義(`/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US`、`/usr/share/i18n/locales/ja_JP`)では`LC_COLLATE`で平仮名が連続していませんでした。
`en_US`には平仮名が含まれていません。
`ja_JP`には平仮名がありますが、連続しているのは「ぁ」から「ん」までで、「ゔ」はそもそも含まれておらず、「ゞ」などは離れた位置にありました。

sayuriさんの回答のように、指定する文字によって動いたりエラーの種類が変わったりするのは、ここらへんの事情が原因のようです。
`C.UTF-8`の定義は平仮名を全て含んでおり、文字コード順に並んでいるので、期待通りに動いています。

Answer (score 8):

手元の環境で試してみました。バージョンは全てGNU sed 4.2.2です。

#### MINGW64

- 全て意図通りの動作

#### Debian

- LANG=en_US.UTF-8

  - 意図通りの動作
- LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8

  - [あ-ん] の場合： 意図通りの動作
  - [あ-ゔ] の場合： エラー「無効な照合文字です」
  - [あ-ゞ] の場合： エラー「無効な範囲終了です」

GNU sedはコンパイルオプションで正規表現エンジンを切り替えることができ、DebianではPCRE 8.35にリンクしていますが、MINGW64ではPCREを使わず（たぶん）標準の正規表現エンジンを使用しています。あとはiconvまわりでしょうか…。

---

なお`s/^[あ-ゞ]+//g`ですと`^`行頭にマッチさせようとしています。また`[あ-ゞ]`は**ぁ**（小さい**あ**）を含んでいません。`s/[ぁ-ゞ]+//g`にすべきかと…。

---

コメントから

> GNU sed のソースコードを眺めてみると `echo "abcあいう123" | LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 sed -re 's/^[あ-ゞ]+//g'` とすれば良い様です。

というようなことはなく`LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8`もしくは`LANG=en_US.UTF-8`で十分です。正しく設定されているかは

```
$ locale charmap
UTF-8
```

の結果が得られるかで確認できます。（ソースコードを見る限り大文字で`UTF-8`となる必要があります。）

Comment: GNU sedでも環境により色々なのですね。正規表現のご指摘も、ありがとうございます。質問に反映させていただきました。

Comment: @mjy さん、回答に合わせて質問文を修正してしまうと回答側が整合しなくなるのでロールバックさせてもらいました（WikiではなくQ&Aサイトですので）。また`ldd /bin/sed`にてダイナミックリンクしているライブラリを確認しPCREを使用しているかも確認してください。